# Fullcalendar - Display an event with no end date

Tags: fullcalendar

How do I go about displaying a long-running event with no end date? The data provided to me only shows when the event started but no end date because it's set to "Forever". It appears that when I only provide the start option, it only sets the event to show up on that day and not the following days.

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible workaround for this, where if there is no end date from the event source, I always set the end date to 24 months from today, but that means if someone navigate the calendar past 24 months, the event would appear to have ended then. Would be nice to have something that will just keep going forever.

Comment: Did you find any better way? I have the same situation